# tcsh shell and variable argument alias

Tags: alias, tcsh

I use tcsh shell and I cannot change to another shell.

I'm trying to create an alias to quickly cd into my project.
My home directory looks like:

```
/home/projects/proj1

/home/projects/proj2
...
/home/stuff/stuff1
```

If i am working in stuff 1 directory and want to quickly navigate to my projects, i created an alias as follows:

```
alias P 'cd /home/projects && cd ./\!:1'
```

so that I can type 'P proj1' to get there

However, sometimes i want to navigate to /home/projects directory instead of a particular project and i thought just typing 'P' (without arguments) will get me there but i'm getting a "Bad ! arg selector". How do i create an aliases to handle zero or more arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
alias P 'cd /home/projects/\!*'
```

If you pass an argument, it is appended to the end of the path, else `!*` is replaced by nothing.